# Is Separable space iff compact space?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm reading chapter2 of Rudin's PMA. In exercise 22~26, it uses separable space.
According to exercises,
compact$\implies$every infinite subset has a limit point$\implies$separable$\implies$countable base.
And in 26, countable base$\implies$compact. Then, compact$\iff$separable?
I've not studied general topology. But I've heard that compact space is not equivalent to separable. Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Is the real line separable? Is it compact?

Comment: I know that euclidean space is separable but not compact. But according to proof of exercise, separable iff compact. What is the problem of this?

Comment: Countable base does not imply compactness. You are reading it wrongly.

Comment: I found where I had misunderstood. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, many readers can guess what PMA stands for, but my advice is this: In future questions do not try to save some words of explanation. What is clear to you, especially if it is an abbreviation, is in general not clear to other people.

Comment: Pakistan Military Academy!

Comment: Look at  this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMA

Comment: Not one of these exercises implies or suggests that all second countable spaces (or separable spaces) are compact. 26 does not say that at all.

Answer (score 0):

The exercises say that compact $\Longrightarrow$ "every infinite subset has a limit point" and later (26) the converse "every infinite subset has a limit point" $\Longrightarrow$ compact. Either implies that $X$ is separable and has a countable base (two properties that are equivalent in any metric space). But $\Bbb R^k$ is separable (see 22) and hence has a countable base (23), but it's certainly not compact, as e.g. $\Bbb Z^k$ does not have a limit point despite being compact.

That two facts both imply a third does not make those two facts equivalent: odd multiples of $3$ and odd multiples of $7$ are both odd integers but not equivalent notions, to name a trivial example.

BTW the fact that compact is equivalent to the limit point fact is also quite specific (but not unique) to metric spaces, in general spaces only one implication holds and compact spaces need not be separable, let alone have a countable base, in the context of general spaces.